# Typescript filter method

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my angular 2 application I have declared 2 object arrays.

```
users: User[];
selectedUsers: User[];
```

Now I am using the `filter()` method to return an array with objects whose checked property is true.

```
this.selectedUsers = this.users.filter(user => user.isChecked == true);
```

The problem is the references for elements of both arrays are same.
So is there a way to that I can filter out objects and return array of new objects(new reference)?

Comment: So you want a new array with a clone of every user which is checked, right?

Comment: That won't work, since filter expects a function that returns a bool and doesn't care for the result. This should work: `this.selectedUsers = this.users.filter(user => user.isChecked == true).map(user => deepCloneUser(user));`. If writing deep clone is too tedious manually lodash & co have utility methods for it.

Comment: @Pablo yes. Basically creating new objects with same properties as the ones that are 'isChecked'.

Answer (score 9):

You can always use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a new object:

```
this.users.filter(user => user.isChecked).map(u => Object.assign({},u));
```

Comment: So in my particular case I would have to write Object.assign(user, u) in order to assign new properties of object u?(As per what I understood in the documentation)

Answer (score 5):

You can use _.cloneDeep function ("lodash" library):

for implement lodash in typescript you need:

```
npm i -S lodash
```

and the @types lib :

```
npm i -S @types/lodash
```

and in your code:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'

let cloneCheckedObject = _.cloneDeep(this.users.filter(user => user.isChecked);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets take @Amir answer and make it a tiny bit more typescript friendly:

```
this.users.filter(user => user.isChecked).map(u => {...u});
```

Comment: the `map` handler is wrong, should be replaced with `({...u})` or a `return`